# PHP call to WordPress function failing

Tags: php, wordpress, destructor

PHP call to the WordPress `wp_create_category($string_value, $int_value)` is going immediately to `__destruct`.

I wrapper the line in `try{...} catch`, but that doesn't change anything. It still goes directly to `__destruct` without passing "GO" or collecting $200.

Comment: Which object `__destruct` you are talking?

Comment: We need more information here, Bob.

Answer (score 0):

You should use wp_insert_term .

```
 $arg = array('description' => "my description", 'parent' => "cat_ID");
 $new_cat_id = wp_insert_term("cat name", "category", $arg);
```